# Is it possible to let a TFS group view work items, but not let them see any of the checked-in code?

Tags: tfs

We have a partner on our project who needs to be able to view TFS work items via the web interface, but we do not want them to have access to view our source code. It seems like it's possible to switch the scenario (access to source control, but not TFS tasks), but I'm not sure how to configure this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely.  The source control permissions can be maintained separately.  Go to the Source control explorer, right click on the team project > Advanced > Security.  Click on the Readers group and remove the "Read" permission.

Mike